# What percent of whey protein powder is converted to tissues?

Tags: protein, whey

Based on my naive knowledge (my background is not in health science, actually engineering), not all intake protein can be converted to tissues like muscle mass and the utilization of each food is different. As I know, the utilization of whey protein (I think %17) is less than that of dairy. I am wondering about the utilization of whey protein powders? If their utilization is not high and the main proportion of it is converted to glucose, why do bodybuilders consume whey protein powder? What are the best substitute for whey protein powders and how to use them?

Comment: Gluconeogenesis occurs when the body needs glucose and can’t create it from carbs, and is sourced from both fats and proteins (well, aminos). The body *avoids* taking energy from protein as much as it can. Once proteins are broken down into amino acids their source is irrelevant—the only thing that matters is the ratios (e.g., lysine/leucine aren’t converted to glucose). If you have references to what you’re asking about it might be helpful because it’s counter to what (admittedly little) I understand about the processes.

Comment: I don't think I completely understand your question, but it sounds to me like you are asking about what's called bioavailability of different proteins (basically how effectively your body can utilize different kinds of protein).  I think people tend to use whey because it has a very high bioavailability (eggs do too).  Maybe helpful to do a google search on bioavailabilty, do some reading and see if that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My question is based on this video. https://youtu.be/YHNHpPGlvSY?list=PL6GlTYAkb-F5cT_WPMyBMzUPofKR8ACDv&t=1350

Comment: There's two things at play here--bioavailability as Travis said, and "what happens to the extra". "Liquid protein" moves through the body quickly, and the body takes time to absorb protein--longer than a liquid protein source allows. See, for example, a study overview: https://www.precisionnutrition.com/rr-whey-too-much (caveat: I didn't read the original study yet, so...?) The excess is excreted. Again, in a calorically-sufficient diet, protein is a last-resort energy source--ketogenic adaptation aims to replace carb sources w/ fat.

Comment: Whey protein continues to have [one of the highest protein utilization rates](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3905294/) only followed by eggs. IMO, I would not take nutrition advice from a *holistic* Chiropractor posing as a Dietician. I would really like to see where these "glucose rates" are from but alas, nothing in the video is cited. Shame.

Comment: @C.Lange Thank you so much for sharing the article. For someone who is new in this journey, it is somewhat difficult to find the best source of information.